# Multiple Switched Outlets Same Circuit

Tags: receptacle

I’m looking for wiring advice to run multiple switched outlets.  5-6 outlet boxes each with their own switch. Each outlet box will power fans in my barn and I want to be able to turn those switches off and on individually.  I have seen how to do it with one switch running them all, leaving the constant hot available for dedicated switches. Just not sure exactly how that additional wiring would look.

Comment: Where do you want those switches to be located: in a central switch panel somewhere, or at the individual outlet boxes? Also, how many HP/amps are the fans in question?

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is to simply run 12/2/grnd to each outlet box from your 5 gang switch box.  That would give you the most flexibility to future proof whatever you are doing. You could run 12/3 and set up a MWBC (Multi Wire Branch Circuit) but currently 12/3 is about double the price of 12/2, so economically it makes no sense right now.

Also, your 5 gang switch box may not have enough fill capacity  for the cables nor power supply.  You may have to run 2 circuits to a 2 gang and a separate 3 gang box to adequately supply your fans.     You need to look at the ratings on the fans and determine what their power requirements are.

Comment: I don't see where the OP has a 5-gang box.

Comment: @Huesmann I think that was implied by "5-6 outlet boxes, each controlled by their own swtich".

Comment: I read that as "five to six outlet boxes."

Comment: @Huesmann  Yeah, but he wanted each one individually controlled by a switch, so I assumed 5-6 switches in a box.    I don't see why this is such a tough problem...just supply each switch with a hot and connect the other pole of the switch to the black going to the outlet box, tie all the neutrals together and your done!   The OP might also consider a sub-panel with a breaker for each outlet box, he could probably run 14/2 which is a lot less expensive than 12/2.  Or if there is already a sub in the barn, go that route. ...getting opinion based here, sorry!

Comment: That's why the answer to ThreePhaseEel's question is important—fans switched at a central location, or switched at each outlet.